# Security of changing permissions of file on server

Tags: php, security, chmod

I have a PHP file which edits an XML file, both on the same web-server. So I need to chmod 666 the XML file. However i've seen some warnings about this being a security risk due to the granted write permissions.

I only care about whether remote users can edit my XML file, am I correct in thinking this is not possible without being local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set them up a group and set a group permission for the file and give that file the group permission and all those users of that group can edit that file. This way, only members of the group can edit and not all public people.

Comment: Problem is, I (think i) need to allow apache to alter XML, which would need chmod to allow all write permissions.

Comment: The idea is, to have the user that executes Apache, or PHP for that matter in the same group as your FTP user.

Comment: I am not sure, but isnt there a way to add apache to that group too? I thought there was, if i find the time (currently at work), i will google around a bit and test. However, i believe that you can add apache to groups.

Comment: Oh wait, just tried it out apparently Apache was already set to be in my group. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Who creates the XML file in the first place? If you create it directly via PHP, you do not need to set such permissions.

If you are on shared hosting, others might be able to modify the XML, depending on the server's configuration.

The security risk depends on what you do with the data, do you eval it, do you call functions according to content in the XML? Do you just output something without escaping? Do you store sensitive information in the XML?

I'm not sure what you mean by "remote users". Any other user that is logged on, read system user, can modify the file. So anyone that is connected via SSH or something could change it.
If it's a virtual server however, it's a different matter.

Comment: The XML is uploaded manually, I have a latitude and longitude, which if blank i geo-code and write to the XML file (using PHP). By remote, I mean say: evil.com/editXML.php reads myHost.com/map.xml would it be able to alter map.xml without logging into my hosting account?

Comment: manually as in FTP? If so, you'd best go with prolink007's solution.
However, this only works if you have shell access and are allowed to modify settings. If you are on shared hosting, it is possible that your PHP instance is being run with the same user as your FTP or that they are in the same group.

Comment: Yeah FTP, and no I dont have shell access. As i'm on shared hosting (i think) would those users would be able to modify the xml file? If so is there anyway to stop this but still allow my PHP to have write permissions?